# How do I test if the element being passed to a function is the document itself?

Tags: javascript, jquery, function, selector, document

I'm writing a small script that injects some code into an HTML element.

All works fine by setting:

```
element.innerHTML = "<p>foo</p>";
```

unless I'm being passed the `document` itself, because both:

```
document.innerHTML
```

and

```
document[0].innerHTML
```

can't be set (at least nothing shows up on my screen :-)

**Question:**
How can I test if the element I'm being passed is the document itself vs. the body or some other HTML element?

Comment: Erm... what's wrong with `element === document`?

Comment: ahm... looks too easy... let me try :-)

Comment: @raina77ow: Nice! Please make it an answer, so I can check.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Well, you can just check whether or not the passed object is identical to `document`:

```
if (element === document) {
   // ...
}
```

Answer (score 2):

You can check by reading the `[[Class]]` property.

```
Object.prototype.toString.call( document ); // [object HTMLDocument]
Object.prototype.toString.call( document.body ); // [object HTMLBodyElement]
```

Respectively, you pass in the passed variable name into the `.call()`.

Comment: @frequent that of course also works, but only as long as you don't deal with a multi-frame or multi-window environment